# Proguard in Android Library

Tags: android, proguard, android-library

I am having an error with the Proguard file in Android.

The point is, I know how to use it in an Android Project, but now, I need to use it for an Android Library Project, and the `.jar` extracted (there is no resources on the library), to obfuscate the code, because I would like to distribute my library for everyone to use it, but with the code obfuscated.

My Android library project is a normal one, I just take the `.jar` with is contained in the "bin" folder from the Library Project, and I am trying to use the Proguard to obfuscate it this way:

```
java -jar proguard.jar @proguard-project -verbose
```

My Proguard file is the next one:

> -injars       in.jar
>   -outjars      out.jar
>
> -libraryjars /home/jorider/wul4/adt-android/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar
>   -libraryjars /home/jorider/wul4/adt-android/sdk/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar
>   -libraryjars commons-codec-repackaged-3.1-b36.jar
>   -libraryjars httpmime-4.2.5.jar
>
> -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
>   -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
>   -verbose
>
> -dontoptimize
>   -dontpreverify
>
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
>   -keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>   -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
>
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
>      native ;
>   }
>
> -keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
>     void set*(***);**
>      get();
>   }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
>     public void *(android.view.View);
>   }
>
> -keepclassmembers enum * {
>      public static **[] values();
>      public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
>   }
>
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>     public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
>   }
>
> -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
>       public static ;
>   }
>
> -dontwarn android.support.**

The result I get for running that on the console is :

```
Shrinking...
java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

Anyone knows why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can find a configuration for processing libraries in the ProGuard manual > Examples > [A typical library](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#library).

Notably, you'll need to preserve all public API:

```
-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is generating me the .jar that I need. The only problem is that, it is so obfuscated that no one project can understand anything.....Anyone knows how can I let the methods of the public API work?